# How to create object of nameless derived class of my abstract class?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

Consider following Java program:

```
abstract class Surprising
{       
    void fun()
    {
        System.out.println("fun() is invoked");
    }
}
class myclass
{
    public static void main(String args[])      
    {
        Surprising s=new Surprising() { };
        s.fun();
    }
}
```

Here I am creating object of nameless subclass of my abstract class Surprising, not the object of abstract class because it isn't allowed to create object of abstract class in Java.

What is the equivalent C++ program? Is it possible to do this in C++? If yes, how & if no, why not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ the `Surprising` class would not be *abstract*, because it defines all of its members. If you want an *abstract* (i.e. not instantiable) class, make at least one of its members pure virtual. Like here:

```
class Surprising
{
public:
    virtual void fun()=0;
};
```

You can then define the member in an anonymous class of which you create an instance and then invoke the newly defined member function on that instance:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    class  : public Surprising
    {
    public:
        virtual void fun() { std::cout << "Surprise!" << std::endl; }
    } inst_;
    inst_.fun();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty big difference with the example in the question. Each anonymous now has to implement the `fun` method. I would suggest adding an additional method that is virtual so the `Surprising` class still has the implementation of `fun`

Comment: It's not necessary to do that, I only did it that way because I had the feeling that OP has a specific reason to make `Surprising` abstract, i.e. to prevent instantiation. One could as well define the `fun()` function in `Surprising` already and then derive a class from it, but what would be the point of sub-classing if the derivate does not add or alter functionality?

Comment: `<Nit-pick>` Would be better to have the anonymous class use the `override` keyword instead of `virtual`. `</Nit-pick>`  Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Lets say we have the class `A`:

```
class A
{
    ...
};
```

Now to create a derivative of it, we use e.g.

```
class B : public A
{
    ...
};
```

Now to create an object of an anonymous class we simply don't provide a class name:

```
class
{
    ...
} anon_object;
```

And finally we combine the two ways, inheritance and anonymous classes:

```
class : public A
{
    ...
} anon_a_derived_object;
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this as on-the-fly as in Java, in the sense of declaring the class as part of the `new` expression. But you can create a local class inside the function and use it:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  class MySurprising : public Surprising {};
  MySurprising s;
}
```

Comment: even more similar would be the anonymous `struct : Surprising {} s; s.fun();`

Comment: @Walter That's what the other answers show. I'll leave mine out of a sense of completeness. This one leaves you the option of allocating dynamically, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences between Java and C++ relevant to this question. I tried to produce the C++ code that most closely matches the Java code in question.

```
#include <iostream>

class Surprising           // class is abstract since it has pure virtual method
{
public:
  virtual void fun() = 0;  // pure virtual method makes the class abstract
};

// we can define the pure virtual method, but not in class
inline void Surprising::fun()
{
  std::cout<<"fun() is invoked\n";
}

int main()
{
  struct : Surprising      // anonymous derived class
  {
    void fun()             // we must provide an implementation of fun()
    {                      // for otherwise this class remains abstract and
      Surprising::fun();   // cannot be instantinated
    }
  } s;                     // object of anyonmous class
  s.fun();
}
```